# Multiple regression with aggregate data

Tags: multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, aggregation

I have a set of panel data and want to do a fixed-effect regression. My data consists of four years of survey data with (nearly) identical structure.

My dependent variable (for each year) is a satisfaction dummy that can be answered with either yes or no. My independent variables are several characteristics people might have (i.e. sex, age, their plan/contract, etc.). These characteristics are all categorical with at most 5 categories. I am supposed to find out which characteristics are most likely to lead to high satisfaction, while dismissing the change in pricing over time.

My problem is that all the data is aggregated. All I know is that a certain percentage of all satisfied/dissatisfied customers has a certain plan, is in a certain age group and so on. I cannot infer if a satisfied man is below age 30 for example, as I do not have individual data.

Which approach could I take to do a regression with my aggregated data? I feel like the answer to this question is not particularly difficult, but I am a software engineer, not a data scientist, so while I have some formal education in the field, I have almost no practical experience.